C++ Monitor mutex thread issue
This code should stop at 15 characters (line), but it does not and it keeps going infinitely. The main problem with this code is that the condition variable logic doesn't allow all threads to recognize when the target max_count of 15 has been reached, causing the program to run indefinitely.
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

class Monitor
{
private:
    string line = "";
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable cv;
    int vowel_count = 0;
    int max_count = 0;

public:
    void AddA(char symbol)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
        cv.wait(lock, [this] { return vowel_count < 3; });
        line += symbol;
        vowel_count++;
        max_count++;
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    void AddBC(char symbol)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
        cv.wait(lock, [this] { return vowel_count >= 3; });
        line += symbol;
        max_count++;
        vowel_count = 0;
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    string getLine()
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
        return line;
    }

    int getVowelCount()
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
        return vowel_count;
    }

    int getMaxCount()
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
        return max_count;
    }
};

void First(Monitor& monitor)
{
    while (true)
    {
        monitor.AddA('A');

        if (monitor.getMaxCount() == 15)
        {
            break;
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}

void Second(Monitor& monitor)
{
    while (true)
    {
        monitor.AddBC('B');

        if (monitor.getMaxCount() == 15)
        {
            break;
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}

void Third(Monitor& monitor)
{
    while (true)
    {
        monitor.AddBC('C');

        if (monitor.getMaxCount() == 15)
        {
            break;
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}

void Print(Monitor& monitor)
{
    while (true)
    {
        cout << monitor.getLine() << endl;

        if (monitor.getMaxCount() == 15)
        {
            break;
        }

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
}

int main()
{
    Monitor monitor;

    thread t1(First, ref(monitor));
    thread t2(Second, ref(monitor));
    thread t3(Third, ref(monitor));
    thread t4(Print, ref(monitor));

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();

    return 0;
}

I have tried various things like changing the amount to be greater or equal to 15, but it ruins it further.

I mean, you have three threads, each adds asynchronously a character and checks if number of characters is exactly 15 to break. Obviously, at least 2 of them will add an extra character only to discover the value above 15 and they'll never break.

Assuming your words have a max length, your add functions need a failure path.
[[nodiscard]] bool AddA(char symbol) {
  unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
  cv.wait(lock, [this] { return vowel_count < 3 || max_count >= 15; });
  if (max_count >= 15) return false;
  line += symbol;
  vowel_count++;
  max_count++;
  cv.notify_all();
  return true;
}

now, modify your loops:
while (monitor.AddA('A'))
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
}

because AddA fails when it hits 15 characters.
Do similar for AddBC and their loops.
The string now hits 15 characters, no more, and the threads terminate properly.

ALX23z thank you for the explanation I adjusted my code and now it works
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

class Monitor
{
private:
    string line = "";
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable cv;
    int vowel_count = 0;
    int max_count = 0;

public:
    void AddA(char symbol)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
        cv.wait(lock, [this] { return vowel_count < 3; });

        if (max_count >= 15)
        {
            return;
        }

        line += symbol;
        vowel_count++;
        max_count++;
        cv.notify_all(); 
    }

    void AddBC(char symbol)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
        cv.wait(lock, [this] { return vowel_count >= 3; });

        if (max_count >= 15)
        {
            return;
        }

        line += symbol;
        max_count++;
        vowel_count = 0;
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    string getLine()
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
        return line;
    }

    int getVowelCount()
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
        return vowel_count;
    }

    int getMaxCount()
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
        return max_count;
    }
};

void First(Monitor& monitor)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (monitor.getMaxCount() >= 15)
        {
            break;
        }

        monitor.AddA('A');

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}

void Second(Monitor& monitor)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (monitor.getMaxCount() >= 15)
        {
            break;
        }
        monitor.AddBC('B');

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}

void Third(Monitor& monitor)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (monitor.getMaxCount() >= 15)
        {
            break;
        }

        monitor.AddBC('C');

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}

void Print(Monitor& monitor)
{
    while (true)
    {
        cout << monitor.getLine() << endl;

        if (monitor.getMaxCount() >= 15)
        {
            break;
        }

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
}

int main()
{
    Monitor monitor;

    thread t1(First, ref(monitor));
    thread t2(Second, ref(monitor));
    thread t3(Third, ref(monitor));
    thread t4(Print, ref(monitor));

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();

    cout << "Done" << endl;
    cout << monitor.getLine() << endl;

    return 0;
}

